# How to manipulate views in recyclerview adapter's viewholder from other activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView img;
    public ImageView downloadBtn;
    private TextView durationView;
    public CheckBox imgCheckBox;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgProfile);
        downloadBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.downloadBtn);
        durationView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        imgCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageCheckBox);

    }
}
```

I want to use 'imgCheckBox' in other Activity!!

how to use view in ViewHolder from other activity?
It is possible?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? It is a bad idea to access view holder item from another activity

Comment: hmm,, I want to change recyclerview viewholder item hide(setvisibillity) when I do something action in mainactivity.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: You can use listener to tell the other activity for the change.